# How to unarchive data with unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios12

I am using `unarchiveObjectWithData` to unarchive data from `NSUserDefaults` and it is working good, but it was deprecated in iOS 12.0.
Xcode suggests to use `unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:`, but this method does not work.

I have an array of objects of my class to unarchive.

I have tried to use `unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:`, also `unarchivedObjectOfClasses:fromData:error:` with all classes (NSArray, NSString, MYCLASS..)

Works

```
NSArray *stored = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Does not:

```
NSArray *stored = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[MYCLASS class] fromData:data error:&error];
```

I am receiving ”The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.„

Comment: And do you have an error?

Comment: Be a bit more specific about your error. "It does not work" is not sufficient.
Most likely one of your classes doesnt conform to NSCoding

Comment: I am receiving `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. `

Comment: The class conforms to NSCoding, also I have tried to archive and unarchive just one object, not all array, and I'm receiving the same error.

Comment: Also NSSecureCoding? How do you encode?

Comment: I am not using secure coding

Comment: I'm just looking to update this in my app. As you are expecting an `NSArray`, do you not need to set class to `NSArray.class`?

Answer (score 26):

`unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error` seems to be pretty undocumented, but I have figured it out.
In your case as you are unarchiving an `NSArray` and assuming the contents of the array are standard classes like `NSString` then this should work for you:

```
NSArray *stored = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSArray class] fromData:data error:&error];
```

However I was unarchiving a custom object `PurchasedSubscription` and this also applies if your `NSArray` contains any custom Classes...
Firstly the `objectOfClass` from the method to unarchive needs to be the class of what you are expecting to be the result.

```
PurchasedSubscription *purchasedSubscription = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:PurchasedSubscription.class fromData:data error:&error];
```

Next, your custom class needs to conform to `NSSecureCoding` so add this to the interface of the class. I assume you already have `NSCoding` implemented.

```
@interface PurchasedSubscription : NSObject <NSCoding, NSSecureCoding>

@end
```

Next your class has to override `supportsSecureCoding` to confirm it is supported

```
+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding
{
    return YES;
}
```

Next, in your `initWithCoder:` method, you need to use `decodeObjectOfClass:key:` instead of `decodeObjectForKey` when decoding each property, again setting the `Class` parameter as the class type of what's being decoded.

```
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [self init];

    if (self)
    {
        ReceiptInfo *receiptInfo = [aDecoder decodeObjectOfClass:[ReceiptInfo class] forKey:@"receiptInfo"];
        return [self initWithReceiptInfo:receiptInfo];
    }

    return self;
}
```

As you can see here, this class also decodes another custom class `ReceiptInfo`, so I had to repeat this process with that class to get it all to work.

Now when I use

```
PurchasedSubscription *purchasedSubscription = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:PurchasedSubscription.class fromData:data error:&error];
```

it securely decodes the `PurchasedSubscription` class by securely decoding the `ReceiptInfo` class as it knows at each step what the class type should be before it decodes it.

---

A note on the opposite `NSEncoding`. You need to use the method

```
archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:
```

instead of

```
archivedDataWithRootObject:
```

With this one, you don't pass in the object class, you pass in the actual object.
In my case, I create the object like so

```
PurchasedSubscription *validSub = [[PurchasedSubscription alloc] initWithReceiptInfo:latestReceipt];
```

and then encode it like this

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:validSub requiringSecureCoding:YES error:&error];
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me, in particular conforming to NSSecureCoding in addition to NSCoding and overriding supportsSecureCoding.

Comment: Can also only conform to NSSecureCoding and leave out NSCoding.

Comment: Shamelessly sharing this closed dupe question with a newbie-friendly, I reckon answer. :D https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043846/3231194

Comment: What is this "&error"? Xcode doesn't accept it.

Comment: You can use `nil` or if you want to check for any error, declare an NSError variable. `NSError *error;` in the line above it. Then after it you can check if error != nil for an error.

Answer (score 3):

I faced up with an issue and follow the @Darren answer, but ***unarchivedObjectOfClass* returns *nil* ! :(**

so i tried a lot of variation and found the only success way is my case:

*supportsSecureCoding* property **must be YES**

and

```
NSArray<MyClassConformedToNSObject_NSCoding_NSSecureCoding *> *arrayOfCustomObjects = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSObject class] fromData:data error:&error];
```