# How to update NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData to NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[fromData:error:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoder, nsarchiving

My app currently uses this deprecated function:

```
id unarchivedObject=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:codedData];
if([unarchivedObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    // currently returns TRUE when reading existing user data.
}
```

To update, I've converted to this:

```
id unarchivedObject=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSDictionary class] fromData:codedData error:nil];
if([unarchivedObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    // currently returns FALSE when reading existing user data.
}
```

The data was originally encoded like this:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:text forKey:@"text"];
}
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder{
    if(self=[super init]){
        text=[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"text"];
}
```

What could be causing the IF statement to return FALSE using the newer code?

Please note that I am concerned primarily with reading existing data stored prior to deprecating the Archiving functions. Simply changing to the newer functions does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! I've been supporting iOS 10.0 so I haven't encountered such issue until I saw this. I was tinkering for an hour and I successfully found the issue.

> What could be causing the IF statement to return FALSE using the newer
>   code?

It's because your `unarchivedObject` object is **nil**!

If you use the parameter `error` in the new method, you would see an error like this:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "This decoder will only
>   decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'QTPerson' does not
>   adopt it." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=This decoder will only decode
>   classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'QTPerson' does not adopt it.

But how do we get the correct value for this `unarchivedObject` and not nil? It would take a couple of steps.

First off, make your model/class conform to `<NSCoding, NSSecureCoding>`

Example:
**QTPerson.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class QTPerson;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

#pragma mark - Object interfaces

@interface QTPerson : NSObject <NSCoding, NSSecureCoding>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And then implement the protocol methods:

**QTPerson.m**

```
#import "QTPerson.h"

@implementation QTPerson

+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding {
    return YES;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:_text forKey:@"text"];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _text = [coder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSString class] forKey:@"text"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

---

And then when archiving an object, you would want to pass `YES` to the parameter `requiringSecureCoding`, like so:

```
QTPerson *person = [[QTPerson alloc] init];
person.text = @"Glenn";

NSData *codedData1 = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:person requiringSecureCoding:YES error:nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:codedData1 forKey:@"boom"];
```

---

Lastly, when unarchiving, just do what you did correctly, like so:

```
NSData *codedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"boom"];

NSError *er;
id unarchivedObject=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[QTPerson class] fromData:codedData error:&er];

if([unarchivedObject isKindOfClass:[QTPerson class]]){
    NSLog(@"TRUE!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"FALSE!");
}
```

Voila! You'll get nonnull object `unarchivedObject`, hence the TRUE/YES value you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the code/research, however after implementing, I still get a null unarchived object when reading existing data - which is the real issue here. I could delete existing data for this app update and start fresh, however existing users of the app will lose their data which I would prefer not to do.

Comment: @wayneh Did you find a solution?

Comment: @DavidvanDugteren No, I have not resolved this yet. At this time I have pulled my Apps from the App Store.